# "Binary/Unary operator '++/<' cannot be applied to an operand of type" AND "Use of unresolved identifier '=-'"

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am translating an Obj-C app to Swift and having trouble dealing with some syntax. I believe I have declared the variable types correctly so I don't know why I'm be getting these errors. Maybe some blocks are located incorrectly inside classes/functions when they should be outside or something. I would love it if you could review my code. I'm new to programming so what may be a clear and explicit explanation to you probably will still be vague for me so please show with examples using existing names.

Thanks

> "Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'Int?'"

and

> "Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'Int? and Float'"

and

> "Use of unresolved identifier '=-'"

[image]

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AVFoundation


let minFramesForFilterToSettle = 10

enum CurrentState {
case statePaused
case stateSampling
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

let session = AVCaptureSession()
var camera : AVCaptureDevice?
var validFrameCounter: Int = 0
var pulseDetector: PulseDetector!
var filter: Filter!
var currentState = CurrentState.stateSampling       // Is this initialized correctly?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.pulseDetector = PulseDetector()
    self.filter = Filter()
    // TO DO startCameraCapture() // call to un-used function.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}

let NZEROS = 10
let NPOLES = 10

class Filter {

var xv = [Float](count: NZEROS + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
var yv = [Float](count: NPOLES + 1, repeatedValue: 0)

func processValue(value: Float) -> Float {

    let gain: Float = 1.894427025e+01

    xv[0] = xv[1]; xv[1] = xv[2]; xv[2] = xv[3]; xv[3] = xv[4]; xv[4] = xv[5]; xv[5] = xv[6]; xv[6] = xv[7]; xv[7] = xv[8]; xv[8] = xv[9]; xv[9] = xv[10]; xv[10] = value / gain;
    yv[0] = yv[1]; yv[1] = yv[2]; yv[2] = yv[3]; yv[3] = yv[4]; yv[4] = yv[5]; yv[5] = yv[6]; yv[6] = yv[7]; yv[7] = yv[8]; yv[8] = yv[9]; yv[9] = yv[10];
    yv[10] =   (xv[10] - xv[0]) + 5 * (xv[2] - xv[8]) + 10 * (xv[6] - xv[4])
    + ( -0.0000000000 * yv[0]) + (  0.0357796363 * yv[1])
    + ( -0.1476158522 * yv[2]) + (  0.3992561394 * yv[3])
    + ( -1.1743136181 * yv[4]) + (  2.4692165842 * yv[5])
    + ( -3.3820859632 * yv[6]) + (  3.9628972812 * yv[7])
    + ( -4.3832594900 * yv[8]) + (  3.2101976096 * yv[9]);
    return yv[10];
}

}

let maxPeriod = 1.5  // float?
let minPeriod = 0.1 // float?
let invalidEntry:Double = -11
let maxPeriodsToStore:Int = 20
let averageSize:Float = 20



class PulseDetector {

var upVals: [Float] = [averageSize]
var downVals: [Float] = [averageSize]
var upValIndex: Int?
var downValIndex: Int?

var lastVal: Float?
var periodStart: Float?
var periods: [Double] = []
var periodTimes: [Double] = []


var periodIndex: Int?
var started: Bool?
var freq: Float?
var average: Float?

var wasDown: Bool?


func reset() {


    for var i=0; i < maxPeriodsToStore; i++ {
        periods[i] = invalidEntry
    }
    for var i=0; i < averageSize; i++ {   // why error when PulseDetector.h said averageSize was an Int?
        upVals[i] = invalidEntry
        downVals[i] = invalidEntry
    }
    freq = 0.5
    periodIndex = 0
    downValIndex = 0
    upValIndex = 0
}

func addNewValue(newVal:Float, atTime:Double) -> Float {
// we keep track of the number of values above and below zero
if newVal > 0 {
upVals[upValIndex!] = newVal
upValIndex++
if upValIndex >= averageSize {
upValIndex = 0
}
}
if newVal < 0 {
downVals[downValIndex] =- newVal
downValIndex++
if downValIndex >= averageSize {
downValIndex = 0
}
}
// work out the average value above zero
var count: Float
var total: Float
for var i=0; i < averageSize; i++ {
if upVals[i] != invalidEntry {
count++
total+=upVals[i]
}
}
var averageUp = total/count
// and the average value below zero
count=0;
total=0;
for var i=0; i < averageSize; i++ {
if downVals[i] != invalidEntry {
count++
total+=downVals[i]
}
}
var averageDown = total/count

// is the new value a down value?
if newVal < (-0.5*averageDown) {
wasDown = true
}
```

// original Objective-C code

```
PulseDetector.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>  

#define MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE 20 // is this an Int?
#define AVERAGE_SIZE 20 // is this a Float?
#define INVALID_PULSE_PERIOD -1 // done

@interface PulseDetector : NSObject {  
float upVals[AVERAGE_SIZE];
float downVals[AVERAGE_SIZE];
int upValIndex;
int downValIndex;

float lastVal;
float periodStart;
double periods[MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE];  //  this is an array!
double periodTimes[MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE]; // this is an rray !!

int periodIndex;
bool started;
float freq;
float average;

bool wasDown;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) float periodStart;  // var periodStart = float?


-(float) addNewValue:(float) newVal atTime:(double) time; // declaring a method called addNewValue with 2 arguments called atTime and time that returns a float
-(float) getAverage; // declaring a method called getAverage that returns a float
-(void) reset; // declaring a method that returns nothing

@end






PulseDetector.m

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "PulseDetector.h"
#import <vector>
#import <algorithm>

#define MAX_PERIOD 1.5
#define MIN_PERIOD 0.1
#define INVALID_ENTRY -100 // is this a double?

@implementation PulseDetector

@synthesize periodStart;


- (id) init
{
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
// set everything to invalid
[self reset];
}
return self;
}

-(void) reset {
for(int i=0; i<MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE; i++) {
    periods[i]=INVALID_ENTRY;
}
for(int i=0; i<AVERAGE_SIZE; i++) {
    upVals[i]=INVALID_ENTRY;
    downVals[i]=INVALID_ENTRY;
}   
freq=0.5;
periodIndex=0;
downValIndex=0;
upValIndex=0;
}

-(float) addNewValue:(float) newVal atTime:(double) time {
// we keep track of the number of values above and below zero
if(newVal>0) {
    upVals[upValIndex]=newVal;
    upValIndex++;
    if(upValIndex>=AVERAGE_SIZE) {
        upValIndex=0;
    }
}
if(newVal<0) {
    downVals[downValIndex]=-newVal;
    downValIndex++;
    if(downValIndex>=AVERAGE_SIZE) {
        downValIndex=0;
    }       
}
// work out the average value above zero
float count=0;
float total=0;
for(int i=0; i<AVERAGE_SIZE; i++) {
    if(upVals[i]!=INVALID_ENTRY) {
        count++;
        total+=upVals[i];
    }
}
float averageUp=total/count;
// and the average value below zero
count=0;
total=0;
for(int i=0; i<AVERAGE_SIZE; i++) {
    if(downVals[i]!=INVALID_ENTRY) {
        count++;
        total+=downVals[i];
    }
}
float averageDown=total/count;

// is the new value a down value?
if(newVal<-0.5*averageDown) {
    wasDown=true;
}

 // is the new value an up value and were we previously in the down state?
if(newVal>=0.5*averageUp && wasDown) {
    wasDown=false;
// work out the difference between now and the last time this happenned
    if(time-periodStart<MAX_PERIOD && time-periodStart>MIN_PERIOD) {
        periods[periodIndex]=time-periodStart;
        periodTimes[periodIndex]=time;
        periodIndex++;
        if(periodIndex>=MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE) {
            periodIndex=0;
        }
    }
// track when the transition happened
    periodStart=time;
} 
// return up or down
if(newVal<-0.5*averageDown) {
    return -1;
} else if(newVal>0.5*averageUp) {
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}

-(float) getAverage {
double time=CACurrentMediaTime();
double total=0;
double count=0;
for(int i=0; i<MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE; i++) {
// only use upto 10 seconds worth of data
    if(periods[i]!=INVALID_ENTRY  && time-periodTimes[i]<10) {
        count++;
        total+=periods[i];
    }
}
// do we have enough values?
if(count>2) {
    return total/count;
}
return INVALID_PULSE_PERIOD;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you didn't copied the defines:

```
#define MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE 20 // is this an Int?
#define AVERAGE_SIZE 20 // is this a Float?
#define INVALID_PULSE_PERIOD -1 // done
```

You have to change your defines so they work in your Swift code.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325477/how-to-use-a-objective-c-define-from-swift) how to replace the Objective-C `#define` to make Swift-Workable.

Also you could just change the defines to variables and initialize your variables with them.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Please check the top part of my Swift code. I added the ViewController class and processValue() function which includes the Obj-C #defines. I actually did declare those defines. In a previous SO question I was told I could declare the macros as Swift constants so that's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

First, a bit on optionals. Variables that end with a '?' are Optional, meaning that they are allowed to be nil (basically not exist). The compiler will not know at compile time whether this variable exists or not, because you are allowed to set it to nil.

"Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'Int?'"

You seem to have read that last word as Int, but it is Int? which is significant. Basically, since it is an optional (as indicated by the question mark), the compiler knows it can be nil. You cannot use ++ on nil, and since optionals can be nil, you cannot use ++ on optionals. You must forcibly unwrap it first:

```
downValIndex!++ //note the exclamation point for unwrapping
```

"Use of unresolved identifier '=-'"

=- isnt a thing. -= is a thing. So

```
downVals[downValIndex] -= newVal
downVals[downValIndex] = downVals[downValIndex]-newVal //equivalent to above
```

"Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'Int? and Float'"

The compiler thinks you have an optional int on the left of the < and a Float on the right. Assuming you want two Ints, you must unwrap the left and make sure the right is cast to be an int (something like this). If you want two floats instead, cast or define as floats instead of ints.

```
if downValIndex! >= averageSize as! Int { //casting to Int
```

You should just be defining averageSize as an int though

```
var averageSize:Int = 10 //or whatever number
```

Also, you have lots of optionals. If any of them can be defined to something at compile time, it will make your life easier as you won't need to unwrap them everywhere. Alternately you could implicitly unwrap them (only do this if you are absolutely sure they will never be nil).

```
var implicitlyUnwrappedOptional:Int!
```

Comment: I thought `=-` was weird too but the original Obj-C code uses `=-`. It's reversed for Swift?  Re: the optionals. Problem is I'm translating a lot of code that is for a camera filter algorithm so even though I can recognize the difference between Int, Float, Double I don't know what they should be initialized as.  Just zero is ok? I have a few remaining errors so not sure what I should do. eg. you said I should cast but then I get a warning message. Please see 3 screenshots. Thanks Will!  http://i.imgur.com/EylCqT7.png ||| http://i.imgur.com/qNDKDC1.png ||| http://i.imgur.com/9Y3ZEiW.png

Comment: Also I don't know how to  fix the "could not find overload for '<'" . I keep reading "overlord"  :)

Comment: Most of your problems just come down to not understanding what types things are. [Some info on arithmetic between different types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300480/how-to-do-arithmetic-between-int-and-float-in-swift)

Comment: The key thing is to just realize that operators such as +=, >, +, and all those, only work on two things of the same type, so you need to either declare them as the same type, convert them to the same type (like in the link i posted), or cast them. Ideally, you should be dealing with the most precise type that you use, which would be Double. So you should declare variables that interact with Doubles also as Doubles, that way you can add them etc.

Comment: The thing is I declared my variables just as they were declared in the original Obj-C code above.  floats,doubles,ints in the `class PulseDetector`. Am I not supposed to declare them the same in Swift?  I declared them as the same but got lots of errors so it makes me think that my Swift syntax is the problem and not the type no? Also I know that `=-` is not a valid operator but it's there in the original Obje-C code as well. http://i.imgur.com/6zDsBVp.png  ||| http://i.imgur.com/exC9hZC.png   ||| http://i.imgur.com/ES6AKXS.png

Comment: In Objective C, x=-3 assigns -3 to x. There are two operators, = and -. In Swift, spaces around operators are significant. x-=3 assumes that -= is a binary operator, which it isn't, so you get an error. You write x = -3 instead. The minus is a unary operator because there is space on the left and no space on the right. = is a binary operator because there is space on both sides. x = - 3 wouldn't work either because = and - would be binary operators. Nicely enforces readable code.

Comment: @gnasher729 ah yes that would make sense.