# Delay using DispatchTime.now() + float?

Tags: swift

What exactly is going on with `DispatchTime.now()`

How come I can't assign the time to wait as a variable?

And How Could I use a variable ?

Given error >>>

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'DispatchTime' and 'Float'

```
var time : Float = 2.2 // <---time 

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2.2 // <---- THIS IS OKAY
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when){

        print("Hello")
    }

    let whenWhen = DispatchTime.now() + time // <---- THIS IS NOT OKAY
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: whenWhen){

        print("Hello")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`DispatchTime.now()` is a double. You cannot add a float and a double value together. (A small explanation about why can't you add values with different types can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24300552/3151675)).

Replace

```
var time: Float = 2.2
```

with

```
var time: Double = 2.2
```

And it will work fine.

Comment: Dang that's clean

Comment: You don't need the `Double`. Just do: `let time = 2.2` and `time` will be a `Double` by default.

Comment: hey dharmesh can you help me?

Comment: @RB1509 Yes, How can I help?

Comment: there is a video in view it's actually lottie animation it's work perfectly but ehwn i am going to record that view it will record with some delay(lang).

Comment: I can not help much this way. Did you try asking a new question?

Comment: my account is actually in banned till last 2 year and i don't know how to remove from ban so can you clear me so i can ask question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226907/discussion-between-rb1509-and-dharmesh-kheni).

Comment: Thanks! The horrible thing about that is Swift compiler returns "Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DispatchTime' and 'Float'" which is not helpful at all

Comment: @DharmeshKheni, how do you know `DispatchTime` is a `Double`? I don't see that in the definition (`public struct DispatchTime : Comparable { ... }`). I also don't see any `typealias`es. Looks like it is a unique `Comparable` struct.

Answer (score 39):

You can use `DispatchTimeInterval` to add time in `DispatchTime`.

For Example :

```
let whenWhen = DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(time)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: whenWhen){

    print("Hello")

}
```

Comment: There we gooooo Thanks Jayesh Thanki

Comment: let whenWhen = DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(Int(time*1000))
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: whenWhen){
            
            print("Hello")
            
        }

Answer (score 6):

The error message pretty much explains it.  You can't add a float and a DispatchTime together as they are different data types.

When you use this line:

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2.2 // <---- THIS IS OKAY
```

you don't specify what type the 2.2 is and the system concludes it is of type DispatchTime and allows it.

However when you use this line:

```
let whenWhen = DispatchTime.now() + time // <---- THIS IS NOT OKAY
```

you have already determined that time is a float and that's where the error is generated.

It's probably easiest to convert like this:

```
DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(Int(time * 1000))
```

Comment: What can I do to use a variable ?